# Design pattern to reduce database reads

Tags: design-patterns, system-design

I have to create a Service, Which has to persist a flag against a userId using the api `void register(String userId)` and also the service has to vend a api `boolean isRegistered(String userId)` which says whether a UserID has registered for the service or not.. I’m planning to have a No-SQL database as a Backend as reads and writes are O(1) I prefer not to change the db store as it is vended by a different service.

Expected Request Per Second for create api is : 10 (10 writes per sec to db)

Expected Request Per Second for isRegistered api is : 10000 (10000 reads per second to db). which means for more than 95% of the request this API will return false and userId for isRegistered are mostly distinct values, So caching would need a more ttl to reap its benefit.

Now I’m trying to optimize number of database reads made by `isRegistered()` call as most of the values returned by this api are going to be false(95% of the time).

What is the best way to design this System/DB. Is there an existing design pattern which I can use to Solve this Problem? like a better way to cache.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "What is the best way to.. " this question is primarily opinion based.. Take a look at cache aside pattern: https://blog.cdemi.io/design-patterns-cache-aside-pattern/

Comment: Thanks , I'm looking for a Design pattern which is suitable for this kind of problem